# strange Error from my opencv2 library while I'm using it in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros

While I'm making my catkin workspace, a very strange and long error comes up with the opencv2 library telling:

```
usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1122:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     value = saturate_cast<uchar>(temp);
                                ^
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1126:17: error: ‘FileNode’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘timezone’?
 void read(const FileNode& node, schar& value, schar default_value)
                 ^~~~~~~~
                 timezone
```

This error actually repeats for many functions in the persistence.hpp header file. Anybody has Idea what shall I do ? Actually this message comes up when the compiler reaches the very line at which the #include  is placed.

This is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(PROJECT_NAME)

find_package(catkin_simple 0.1.0 REQUIRED )
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

add_definitions(-std=c++11 -g)
add_definitions(${OpenCV_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})


link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}  src/PROJECT_NAME)
target_link_Libraries ( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

and This is the Package.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>project_name</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description> Whatever </description>


  <maintainer ji3k3</maintainer>


  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin_simple</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>roscpp</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>OpenCV</buildtool_depend>


<depend>OpenCV</depend>
<depend>rosbag</depend>
<depend>roscpp</depend>
<depend>tf</depend>
<depend>pcl_ros</depend>

</package>
```

Comment: Anybody got the chance to take a look at this matter ? I am still trying to solve this issue which has wasted my time a lot.

Comment: Maybe this may help you. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/72925